# Javascript - Hide a tooltip after N seconds, but on my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a tooltip **at the same time** that my current script shows a div (**gift**) if a condition is met:

`if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { $('#gift-1').show();`

The same goes for `#gift-2` :

`if(total > 3000 && total < 4500) { $('#gift-2').show();`

At that moment the corresponding tooltip should be visible:

```
#gift-1 = .tooltip-1
#gift-2 = .tooltip-2
```

And these should be shown **only for 9 seconds**, then disappear until the div ( `#gift -1 or the div #gift-2` ) is shown again:

I tried something like this, but it has not worked for me:

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { $('#gift-1').show();
$('.tooltip-1').fadeOut('slow');},9000);
```

> I am learning JS (novice, level 0) and the truth is that I do not know
>   how I should approach this issue.

Any ideas...?

Thank in advance!

//-------------

**HTML**

```
<div class="tooltip-1"></div>
<div class="tooltip-2"></div>

<div id="gift-1"></div>
<div id="gift-2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip-1,.tooltip-2 {display:none}
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function manageRegalo() {
        var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
        var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
        if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
            total = totalStorage;
        }

        if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
          $('#gift-1').show();
        }
        else{
          $('#gift-1').hide();
        }
      }

      $(document).on('click', function (event) {
          const target = event.target;
          if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
            manageRegalo();

            localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
          }
        });
      manageRegalo();
    });

// -------------------------------------------------

$(document).ready(function(){
      function manageRegaloDos() {
        var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
        var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
        if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
            total = totalStorage;
        }

        if(total > 3000 && total < 4500) {
          $('#gift-2').show();
        }
        else{
          $('#gift-2').hide();
        }
      }

      $(document).on('click', function (event) {
          const target = event.target;
          if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
            manageRegaloDos();

            localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
          }
        });
      manageRegaloDos();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a bit difficult to exactly grasp all of your question. A fiddle ([jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)) is always helpful so maybe next time you can make one.

However, if I understand your question correctly the problem is not *showing* the tooltip but fading it out after 9 seconds, right?

I think you can change this code:

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { 
  $('#gift-1').show();
  $('.tooltip-1').fadeOut('slow');
},9000);
```

... to this code: (actually your code probably will produce a syntax error?):

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { 
   $('#gift-1').show();
   $('#tooltip-1').show(); // Maybe you did this already then you don't need this line.
   window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip-1').fadeOut('slow');
   },9000);
}
```

EDIT: To respect the additional info that a tooltip should only show once there are various ways to go. One would be to store the tooltips in eg. a window. variable. The other would be via CSS classes. I use CSS classes here (this is untested code):

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { 
   $('#gift-1').show();
   if (!$('#tooltip-1').hasClass('alreadyShown')) {
      $('#tooltip-1').show().addClass('alreadyShown');
      window.setTimeout(function(){
         $('.tooltip-1').fadeOut('slow');
      },9000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, **sborn** Brilliant, clean, efficient... +10... Cheers!

Comment: @Pablo_Web — sborn's suggestion of a fiddle is pretty good -- being able to demonstrate the problem you're asking about is very helpful -- but you don't need jsfiddle.net ... right here on SO you can use "stack snippets" and it will be in your question, no need to pop out to jsfiddle or someplace similar. When asking a question, just press the button that looks like a page with `<>` on it, just to the right of the _Image_ button.

Comment: **sborn**, Is it possible that the `.tooltip`, when it is displayed, can only be once, and that the script ignores the new calls to be shown...? .. I only want to show the tooltip once (at least until the user reloads the page, of course). It's annoying (bad UX), that the `.tooltip` is showing every time you click until you reach the max limit of value...

Comment: **@Stephen**, I already know it. I have asked many times with the contribution of functional script (here, with snippet, in Fiddle and Pen). It happens that today it was too complex for me to extract the divs, css. etc for a functional representation. Thanks for your help. Greetings.

Comment: @Pablo_Web - as you already saw I updated the answer in order to respect tooltips only showing once. (This is just for info for users finding this issue later)